# R-duplicates with different measures

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-cleaning

I'm working with a messy census data set where there are duplicates in the `variable` column (`high school`, and `university`) but theses duplicates are actually measuring something slightly different. The measure where the number is higher in the `count` column is the total for those 15 and over (`highest_educ_15_over`). And the lower number is always that of highest education for 24-65 (`highest_educ_24_65`). Here is the data for a visual.

```
data <- tribble(
  ~town, ~variable, ~count,
  "A","highest_educ_15_over",100,
  "A","high school",80,
  "A","university",20,
  "A","highest_educ_24_65",50,
  "A","high school",40,
  "A","university", 10,
  "B","highest_educ_15_over",1000,
  "B","high school", 800,
  "B",   "university", 200,
  "B",  "highest_educ_24_65", 500,
  "B", "high school", 400,
  "B", "university", 100)
```

I can't simply filter for high school or university because it return both values. Eventually I won't like the data set to look like this:

```
tribble(
  ~town, ~highest_educ_15_over, ~highschool, ~university,
  "A", "100","80","20",
  "B", "1000","800","200"
  )
```

Where I automatically take the highest value for `high school` and `university` for each town and corresponding total denominator.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: Can you clarify what your expected output is? "Eventually I won't like the data set to look like this" is not clear. Also, how do you intend to calculate "total denominator"?

Answer (score 1):

We can do a group by sequence and then with `pivot_wider` change it to 'wide' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(town, variable) %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = variable, values_from = count)  %>% 
  filter_at(3:ncol(.), all_vars(!is.na(.))) %>%
  select(-rn)
```

Comment: Maybe just add a filter call to filter out NAs. `filter(!is.na(highest_educ_15_over))`